# What is the proper way of handling AWS credentials in an Android project?

Tags: java, android, security, amazon-web-services

I need to connect to Amazon's SimpleDB in my Android app. The sample project provided with Amazon's [Android SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/) places the credentials in a file called AwsCredentials.properties, which is in the project source. The source code then makes these calls to access and use them:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load( getClass().getResourceAsStream( "AwsCredentials.properties" ) );

String accessKeyId = properties.getProperty( "accessKey" );
String secretKey = properties.getProperty( "secretKey" );
...
credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials( properties.getProperty( "accessKey" ), properties.getProperty( "secretKey" ) );
```

Is this the proper and secure way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't do it that way. It is suitable for quickly putting something together but storing AWS credentials in a properties files is not the secure way to do it. Amazon actually provide an useful write-up on [how to access AWS securely from a mobile device](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/SDKs/Android/4611615499399490). I would also suggest looking at the [KeyStore provided by Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html).

I have written more details about [using IAM users for mobile AWS credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497660/having-trouble-understanding-how-to-use-the-android-aws-sdk/6537065#6537065) in my response to your other question.

Comment: I've looked into using the KeyStore, but I have no idea how to use it, and I have never dealt with cryptographic security with Java before. First, does the KeyStore represent the actual credential storage on the phone? And secondly, if my access key and secret key have never been on the phone before, how would I get my keys into this KeyStore without shipping it with my app?

Comment: Yes, the KeyStore is the credential storage. For your second question you would need to register or authenticate the app user, then create an IAM user (on a remote server/EC2 instance) or reuse an IAM user for a returning app user, and then get the app to retrieve the new IAM user's credentials. I recongize it's not a seamless workflow, there may be better ways to do it for your use case that I am not aware of.

Comment: The user of my app will need to access a single master database. I won't need to distinguish one user from another, at least in this initial stage of development. Do I need to go through the IAM stuff and whatever you just described? And it also sounds like I need to spin up some sort of server for the app to get its credentials. Am I right?

Comment: In that case maybe just one IAM user with the minimal permissions needed for your app might work? I definitely wouldn't embed the AWS user, at least with an IAM user you can set specific permissions and just use the access key and secret key for that user.

Comment: Hi @BenM, If I have understood it correctly, you are talking about some alternative role credentials, but still we need to store it on android app. Now Playstore also rejects the app, if we hardcode the credentials. Any idea?