# Is it a good idea to store the AWS Access and Secret keys in MODE_PRIVATE shared preferences?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a android project, there is a need to upload images to the AWS S3 and I have decided to use AmazonS3Client it is working in latest android but it is a deprecated method to upload files on S3

To follow this approach I have to get secret and access keys. currently I'm getting these keys from an API and after user logs in the app I'm storing them in private mode in shared preferences

please guide me I'm new to this android AWS S3 integration what should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of handling AWS credentials in an Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501254/what-is-the-proper-way-of-handling-aws-credentials-in-an-android-project)

Comment: Not knowing much about the specifics of this particular implementation, my advice is that it's always a bad idea to store access keys within a client.  Can you make that particular location public and just use a HTTP client to transfer the data instead?  Another approach might be to put CloudFront in front of the S3 bucket and restricting what the OAI permissions to S3 are.

Comment: If you have to store credentials, they should be temporary, that is, issued by a service such as the Secure Token Service (STS) in AWS.